# This question is very clear however it was put on hold

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/if-companies-can-afford-a-counter-offer-why-dont-they-pay-that-before-the-empl) has recently been put on hold for being "unclear as to what you're asking". Why? It's clear what the question is, what's the hangup?

Comment: Looks from the history as if it was largely due to it having such a poor title, rather than the content of the actual question